# coreplot 2 plots in graph

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-plot

im currently creating a graph for an app, using coreplot and have a problem i cant explain.

i read (and it didnt help):
[core-plot, unable to plot two graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013197/core-plot-unable-to-plot-two-graphs)

**QUESTION: why does only the second added plot get displayed? if i change the order i add them to the hostView, only the last one i add is displayed. see code & screenshots below.**

the graph will hold 2 different plots

```
PROBLEM:
- both plots show perfectly if added alone.
- if i add both plots, only the second (last) one added gets displayed.
- to assure you that both are well on their own i added screenshots on the bottom.
```

**First Plot** a single 0 line

```
identifier : @"nullLine"
name: nullPlot
```

**Second Plot** a scatterplot of data i have stored

```
identifier : @"balanceChart"
name: plot
```

here is some of my code:

```
    CPTGraphHostingView *host = [self buildGraphView];   //returns a viewwithframe
    [view addSubview:host];

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc ]initWithFrame:host.frame];
    host.hostedGraph = graph;

    CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init ];
    plot.dataSource = self;
    [plot setIdentifier:@"balanceChart"];

    // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(20.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-200.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(400.0)];

    CPTScatterPlot *nullPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init ];
    nullPlot.dataSource = self;
    [nullPlot setIdentifier:@"nullLine"];
    [nullPlot setPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    [plot setPlotSpace:plotSpace];


    [graph addPlot:nullPlot];
    [graph addPlot:plot];
```

and my `doubleForPlot` function:

**NOTE:** i only add this function for completion - it does absolutely to 100% return the right values for both graphs!

```
-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

// NULL CHART
if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"nullLine"]) {
    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
        NSLog(@"Plot: %@,fieldEnum: %d, index: %d",plot,fieldEnum,index);
        return index+1;
    }
    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY) {
        NSLog(@"Plot: %@,fieldEnum: %d, index: %d",plot,fieldEnum,index);
        double zero = 0;
        return zero;
    }
}


// BALANCE CHART
if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"balanceChart"]) {

    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {

        NSLog(@"Axis: %d and Value: %d",fieldEnum, index+1);
        return (double)(index+1);
    }

    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY) {

        int dayInt = [dataHandler getDayNumber:[NSDate date]].intValue;
        double total = 0;
        for (Expense *exp in [allMonthExpenses objectAtIndex:index]) {
            total = total + exp.value.doubleValue;
        }

        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-(dayInt-(int)index-1)*(60*60*24))];

        double budgetValue = [dataHandler getSpecificBudgetForDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-(dayInt-(int)index-1)*(60*60*24))] ];
        total = budgetValue+total;    

        NSLog(@"\n Axis:%d \n Record for Day: %@ \n IndexForPlot: %d \n Value: %.2f \n",fieldEnum, date,index,total);

        return total;
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

here comes the `numberOfRecordsForPlot` method:

**NOTE** both plots have the same amount of records. this does also return the right number.

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{    
return [dataHandler getDayNumber:[NSDate date]].intValue;

}
```

[image: balanceChart]

[image: nullLine]

**sidenote** dont mind the formatting of the plots please ;-)

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: in the box on top: PROBLEM: only the last added plot gets displayed. i cant display both at the same time. the question obviously is: why and where did i go wrong =) i added a clear question on top - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in a test app and it worked fine—both plots showed up. There must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: that was my worst fear.. do you haveany idea what coud cause such behaviour? might it be that the problem is that my hostingview is addes as a aubvie to a tableview?

Comment: i think you led me to a possible solution..
the code i posted here is a stripped version - i left out all axis declaration etc, apparently without them it works. ill try rebuilding the graphs step by step from this starting point (my question code) until it breaks and then i'll now what caused it. thanks =)

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger Did you figure out what caused the first graph not to be displayed correctly?..cause I am facing same problem..I have 3 views hosting 3 different graphs but only last one is being displayed correctly..Any clue would be great..Thanks!!

Comment: @Eric Skroch Can you guide me please solving this problem..I am struggling with it since a day...really desperate to know the answer so that i can move on..thanks..

Comment: @ShikhaShah Ask a new question with the details of your situation. Not very many people will see your comment here on a question that is over a year old.

Comment: @ShikhaShah i sadly cannot remember what the problem was - i think as i posted here as comment it was not the complete code & and i rebuilt it completely and then it worked..

Comment: @EricSkroch Thanks for your response and sorry for my late reply..here  is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280138/not-able-to-plot-3-graphs-in-3-different-views-using-core-plot-ios....I would really appreciate any help..thanks!!