# Not able to plot 3 graphs in 3 different views using core-plot iOS

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core-plot library to plot a graph in 3 different view..Problem is among all of 3 only 3rd graph get displayed correctly...But if I draw each graph separately then they always shows up right..Any clue would be of great help .Thanks

```
  //In ViewWillAppear  

  -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

   dataPoints     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   // Create graph from theme
  CPTgraph1 = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
  [CPTgraph1 applyTheme:theme];

  CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace1;
  plotSpace1= (CPTXYPlotSpace *)CPTgraph1.defaultPlotSpace;

  CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot1 = [(CPTScatterPlot *)[CPTScatterPlot alloc]       initWithFrame:CPTgraph1.bounds];

  CPTgraph2 = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  //CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
  [CPTgraph2 applyTheme:theme];

  CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2;
  plotSpace2= (CPTXYPlotSpace *)CPTgraph2.defaultPlotSpace;

  CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot2 = [(CPTScatterPlot *)[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CPTgraph2.bounds];

  CPTgraph3 = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  //CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
  [CPTgraph3 applyTheme:theme];

  CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace3;
  plotSpace3= (CPTXYPlotSpace *)CPTgraph3.defaultPlotSpace;

  CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot3 = [(CPTScatterPlot *)[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CPTgraph3.bounds];

  [self plotGraph:graph1 withData:"SomeData" withGraph:CPTgraph1 withPlotSpace:plotSpace1 withCPTScatterPlot:dataSourceLinePlot1];

  [self plotGraph:graph2 withData:"Some Data" withGraph:CPTgraph2 withPlotSpace:plotSpace2 withCPTScatterPlot:dataSourceLinePlot2];

  [self plotGraph:graph3 withData:"Some Data" withGraph:CPTgraph3 withPlotSpace:plotSpace3 withCPTScatterPlot:dataSourceLinePlot3];

}


-(void)plotGraph :(CPTGraphHostingView *)graphView withData:(NSMutableArray*)refData    withGraph:(CPTXYGraph *) graph withPlotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *) plotSpace withCPTScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)dataSourceLinePlot


{

[self readFromData:refData];


graphView.hostedGraph = graph;

graph.paddingLeft   = 0.0;
graph.paddingTop    = 0.0;
graph.paddingRight  = 0.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 10.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 10.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 10.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 10.0;

graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill = graph.plotAreaFrame.fill;
graph.plotAreaFrame.fill          = nil;

graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius    = 0.0;


plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(minimumValueForXAxis)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble( maximumValueForXAxis)];

  plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(minimumValueForYAxis)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(ceil(  (maximumValueForYAxis - minimumValueForYAxis) / majorIntervalLengthForY ) * majorIntervalLengthForY)];



CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

// Grid line styles
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
x.majorIntervalLength   = CPTDecimalFromDouble(majorIntervalLengthForX);
x.labelOffset           = 5.0;


x.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
y.majorIntervalLength   = CPTDecimalFromDouble(majorIntervalLengthForY);
y.labelOffset           = 5.0;
y.majorGridLineStyle    =  majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle    =  minorGridLineStyle;

y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Data Source Plot";

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth              = 1.0;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];
dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];


}
```

Method readFromData will just calculate the x , y values and store it in dataPoints array.

Just elaborate a bit more...graph does shows up in first and second views but seems out of range cause i can only see part of it...but the third graph gets displayed correctly..i guess it has something to do with range or axis..

[image: plot]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what happens when you try to display all 3?

Comment: posting images in a moment

Comment: @andrewlattis  I added the screenshot

Comment: that looks like the graphs are loading completely, but it seems like an issue with the data source.

Comment: data source is fine coz when I comment other 2 graphs and run individually then it plots perfectly fine..

Comment: are there any variables used in the data source methods that are re-used between the 3 graphs?

Comment: But all variables are getting reinitialized..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three plots use the same plot ranges for their plot spaces. Does your plot data fit in that range? If not, you'll need to calculate different plot ranges for each graph.